# First app_requests from FB.ui shows popup window on SSL with chrome

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

When I try to send app_requests from a my app, everything is fine with firefox. (Both on HTTPS and on HTTP)
But when the app is run from chrome, things work fine in HTTP (non-secure). But when it comes to HTTPS, instead of showing a lightbox (i.e. js generated dialog, on the same page), a new popup window is created and the lightbox is shown in that popup window.

This causes the app to break (as popups are, by default, blocked by chrome and the user doesn't necessary click on allow popups from this website)

Moreover, this happens only when the first request is made in an instance of app. When I click on the Invite button again, all the browsers show the lightbox modal (Even chrome)

Here is the JS code used:

```
FB.ui({"method": 'apprequests',"message": "<?=(INVITE_MESSAGE)?>","title":"<?=(INVITE_TITLE)?>","to": user_ids)}, 
function(response){if(response)info();}
);
```

I am not using any special code (Either in PHP or JS) for my app (Somebody said I need to).
The app is, on the whole built on PHP SDK from facebook.

Comment: Do you get any messages in Chrome’s JavaScript error console?

Comment: A warning saying: The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=11#cb=f8f04fc3&origin=http%3A%2F%2Ffbapp01.theappbin.info%2Ffa2354bd&domain=fbapp01.theappbin.info&rela...

You can see it at http://fbapp01.theappbin.info

Comment: Sorry, can’t help you there … but an app called “My Latest Profile Visitors” will get banned by FB soon anyway, because apps offering the kind of functionality the name suggests are against the TOS, IIRC.

Comment: This app is just a sample app built out of an customizable app template I am writing. It's just a random title I chose for the app. Thanks for your help tough. :)

Comment: You’re embedding the JS SDK referencing it with `http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`, even on the SSL version of your app page – make that `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`, without the hard-coded protocol, and see if the problem still persists after that.

Comment: IT seems to work, but even now, sometimes it shows a popup. Maybe some problem with the all.js not loading completely or something.?